# Job to remove logins on secondary replica that don't exist in primary replica

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, jobs

How to remove logins on a secondary replica that don't exist in primary replica?

I want to create automated jobs that should check if the login still exists on a secondary after the login on the primary dropped. I want to drop this login on the secondary replica.

Comment: I tried to improve the wording of your question. Please check that it reflects your intent and [edit] as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a linked server to the primary and write an Agent job that compares the logins on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

You may also write a [trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55912/how-to-prevent-dropping-sysadmin-user-by-another-user-in-sql-server) for `drop_login` wherein code will be to drop the login from secondary server first before performing drop on Primary server.

This will prevent scenario wherein you have a login which is dropped from primary but still available on secondary.

You can also synchronize them using [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/synchronize-logins-between-availability-replicas-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-group/) tutorial.